# Haskell multiply Int and real number

Tags: haskell, types, int, monomorphism-restriction, real-datatype

I have

```
coefficient :: ???????
coefficient = 1.0
```

and

```
val :: Int
```

and I would like to do

```
result :: ???????
result val coefficient = val * coefficient
```

What type signatures and conversion functions do I need to do to make this work? What must I do on top of that if I want to have ability to generalize val to any kind of Num?

This:

```
coefficient = 1.0

val :: Int
val = 3

result :: Num a => a
result = coefficient * (fromIntegral val)
```

gives me this compiler warning:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Double)
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for result :: Num a => a
  at Move.hs:17:1-41
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for result :: Num a => a at Move.hs:17:1
In the first argument of `(*)', namely `coefficient'
In the expression: coefficient * (fromIntegral val)
In an equation for `result':
    result = coefficient * (fromIntegral val)
```

I know thats not what I asked originally, I made some mistakes when sanitizing my code.

Now with a type for coefficient:

```
coefficient :: Num a => a
coefficient = 1.0

val :: Int
val = 3

result :: Num a => a
result = coefficient * (fromIntegral val)
```

the resulting error:

```
Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from the literal `1.0'
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for coefficient :: Num a => a
  at Move.hs:12:1-17
Possible fix:
  add (Fractional a) to the context of
    the type signature for coefficient :: Num a => a
In the expression: 1.0
In an equation for `coefficient': coefficient = 1.0
```

Comment: Your error is the result of defauling and the monomorphism restriction.  Give `coefficient` a type signature.

Comment: What should the type signature be? I tried Double, and got the same error.

Comment: `coefficient :: (Num a) => a`

Comment: @singpolyma That didn't seem to help. I got a different error though, which I edited into the question.

Comment: you shoul do what the error suggests and add `Fractional a` to the context of `coefficient`, which will likely force you to add that to `result` as well.  The basic problem is that `result` must be the same type as `coefficient` (at least jut now) and your signatures do not match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a function, fromIntegral, which will convert an integral number to any other numeric type. So you can do:

```
result :: (Integral n, Num m) => n -> m -> m
result val coefficient = fromIntegral val * coefficient
```

Or, in point-free style:

```
result = (*) . fromIntegral
```

#### Update about updated question(@Drew)

Consider this code:

```
coefficient :: (Num a) => a
coefficient = 1.0
```

This is invalid on it's own, as follows. Because 1.0 is a literal for a fractional number (not a whole integer), then GHC can only encode it as any type which is capable of representing fractional numbers (forall a. Fractional a => a). However, you have specified that it must be valid for any numeric type (forall a. Num a => a). Some numeric types (e.g. Integer) cannot represent fractional values, and are not instances of Fractional (rightly so), so this cannot typecheck. You can fix this as follows:

```
coefficient :: (Fractional a) => a
coefficient = 2.0
```

Here GHC can infer the type, and coefficient works fine. It is important to note, that Fractional is a subclass of Num, so everything that is a Fractional must also be a Num. If we look at the function in the first part of my answer, coefficient is only required to be a Num type (as we only use it with (*)), so we can use this definition of coefficient in place of that parameter. Your problem occurs for exactly the same reason.

```
result :: (Num a) => a
result = coefficient * fromIntegral val
```

Again, the result of this function must be of the same type as coefficient. As coefficient cannot be any Num type, but only a fractional type, we need to change this to:

```
result :: (Fractional a) => a
result = coefficient * fromIntegral val
```

And then that should typecheck. @singpolyma is right that your original error was partly to do with the monomorphism restriction, but you just needed to make the type signatures slightly more specific. If you want it to work with (Num a) => a, then coefficient must be a whole number (e.g. 1).

#### Update about GHCi (@Marcin)

For using this in GHCi, I would suggest letting GHCi infer the type. If in this case you type (in GHCi):

```
let result val coefficient = fromIntegral val * coefficient
```

Then GHCi will correctly infer the type of the result. You can ask GHCi what type it thinks something is using the ':t' command:

```
Prelude> :t result
result :: (Integral a1, Num a) => a1 -> a -> a
```

If you must have an explicit type signature you can do:

```
let result = (\val coefficient -> fromIntegral val * coefficient) :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b -> b
```

To try and have an explicit type, but GHCi will make this monomorphic:

```
Prelude> :t result
result :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Which we don't want (this is because the type annotation refers to the value of the lambda expression, not the declaration of result). I don't know how to get the explicit type to work here either, so maybe someone more knowledgeable than us can answer :P

Comment: That gives me a compiler error. I've added the error and the exact code that is causing it to my post (Its slightly different from what I asked originally. Made some mistakes while sanitizing.

Comment: How would one use a type declaration like this in GHCi, for those of us who are completely new to haskell?

Comment: @Drew, Marcin, I have updated my answer to hopefully answer both your questions.