# why can't I mix two primitives in a function?

Tags: haskell

I am trying out Haskell following ['Haskell the hardway'](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Haskell-the-Hard-Way/) and I am stuck at understanding the basic type system. I have the following code and the haskell is complaining it can't process the function.

```
f3 :: Num -> Int -> Num
f3 x y = x + y
```

I take it, it has to do something with currying or the basic model where haskell converts f x y to (f x) y but if I want to pass and Int to Y, can I do it? if I can how would I do it?

Comment: `Num` isn't a type, but a typeclass. Also `(+)` expects both arguments to be of the same type.

Comment: I did not know about that restriction. Coming from imperative world, wouldn't it be a restrictive?

Comment: I will read the provided link, thanks.

Comment: Haskell does not have any automatic type coercions because the type system would get super complicated and hard to use with them.

Comment: Please see the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13358657/414413. The short answer is `f3 :: Num a => a -> Int -> a` and can be defined as `f3 x y = x + (fromIntegral y)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I take it, it has to do something with currying or the basic model where haskell converts f x y to (f x) y

No. It has  — as almost always in the Haskell world — to do with types. First of all, `Num` is a typeclass, not a type. Types can be *instances*  of a typeclass, for example `Int`, `Integer` and `Double` are instances of `Num`. Now, lets have a look at plus' type:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Aha! It takes two arguments of type `a`, and returns an `a`, where `a` needs to be an instance of `Num` (also called *constraint*).

Now we have enough information to revisit `f3`:

```
f3_wrong_sig :: Num -> Int -> Num
```

After the discussion above, it's clear that `f3_wrong_sig` has a wrong signature. Instead of `Num`, it needs `a` constrained by `Num`:

```
f3_wrong_implementation :: Num a => a -> Int -> a
f3_wrong_implementation x y = x + y
```

However, if we remember the type of `(+)`, `x + y` is only possible for `a` and `Int` being equivalent (also written `a ~ Int`). We need a way to get create another numeric type from `Int`: we need a function `Num a => Int -> a`. Lets inspect some information about `Int` in GHCi:

```
ghci> :i Int
data Int = GHC.Types.I# GHC.Prim.Int#   -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
-- omitted
instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Num Int -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
-- omitted
```

`Int` is not only an instance of `Num`, but also of `Integral`. A quick [hoogle search](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Integral%20b%2C%20Num%20a%29%20%3D%3E%20b%20-%3E%20a) gives us [`fromIntegral :: (Integral b, Num a) => b -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral), which we can plug in and finally get what we want:

```
f3 :: Num a => a -> Int -> a
f3 x y = x + fromIntegral y
```

At that point, we can also take a final step to make this even more general, since `fromIntegral` works for *any* `Integral`:

```
f3_general :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a
f3_general x y = x + fromIntegral y
```

This is also the type GHC would infer.

Answer (score 1):

Next reasons:

1) There is no such type as `Num`

2) Both arguments of `(+)` function must have the **same** type

Possible solutions:

```
f3 :: Int -> Int -> Int

f3 :: Double -> Double -> Double

f3 :: Num a => a -> a -> a        -- could add any numerical type
```

Comment: And many other combinations, e.g. `f3 :: Num a => Double -> Int -> a`

Comment: @Zeta Not with that function body.

Comment: @augustss: True, wasn't taking that into account.